# Troubleshooting circuit in make Electronics Book (Experiment 8)

Tags: relay, oscillator

I created the same circuit as in Experiment 8 of make Electronics book but cannot get it to work in the same way as described in the experiment. When I connect the circuit to the power source and press the push button, i hear the relay make the click noise but the LEDs don't lit up. Only the relay makes the clicking noise (like it's continuously switching. If I remove the capacitor, one of the LED's do lit up (as it should). A picture of my circuit is attached. I am using a 1K resistor in the circuit. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.[image]

[Schematic from the book](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596153755-files/mkel_02/mkel_02_074.pdf)

Comment: Attach a picture of the circuit from the textbook.

Comment: And draw out a schematic for the circuit on the board.

Comment: What is your power supply voltage? HE LI SHUN HLS-14F3L-DC12V-C is a 12V form 1C relay. The coil requires 12VDC to switch reliably. Found data sheet on http://www.helishun.com/c-hls-14f3.html (suggest use google translate.)

Comment: Supply voltage is 12V. I have added the link to the schematic

Comment: That isn't a proper schematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the breadboard wiring diagram, I think the schematic must look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFPuUx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I don't have access to your original source, so I'm only guessing your component values.

Looks like it's intended to oscillate by switching the relay on and off as long as power is applied through momentary switch SW1. The oscillation frequency will depend on C1 and the mechanical pull time and release time of the relay.

The LEDs are polarized -- if they are installed backwards, they won't light up. You mentioned you saw one of the LEDs light up, so at least you know that one of them is connected correctly. I think the LEDs are not an essential part of what makes this circuit oscillate, they are just used here as a visual indicator.

Is possible that the LEDs are in fact lighting up, but only very briefly? Try with the room dark, in case the LEDs are very dim.

Comment: I don't see why the relay switch would oscillate. As long as the button is pressed, the coil should be powered so the switch should always be one way.

Comment: The relay coil is only powered through the Normally Closed contacts, when the coil is energized then the NC contacts become open, and the coil is no longer energized at that time. Once the contacts return to normal (de-energized) position then the cycle repeats.

Answer (score -1):

bro, as i see in schematic from the book ,it seems that it uses **3 resistor** and one **led**, and a **transistor** but you didn't use any of them , maybe that's the problem.